# Can I run Percona xtrabackup on my desktop?

Tags: percona, xtrabackup

I have successfull running xtracbackup on the db server, but I really want to run the backup on the other machine (not the machine that have the MySQL running).
I try to run the xtrabackup tool on my desktop given the host/port options but getting these error:

```
InnoDB Backup Utility v1.5.1-xtrabackup; Copyright 2003, 2009 Innobase Oy
and Percona LLC and/or its affiliates 2009-2013.  All Rights Reserved.

This software is published under
the GNU GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2, June 1991.

150424 16:40:59  innobackupex: Connecting to MySQL server with DSN 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup;host=192.168.33.10;port=3306' as 'vagrant'  (using password: YES).
150424 16:40:59  innobackupex: Connected to MySQL server
IMPORTANT: Please check that the backup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful backup run innobackupex
           prints "completed OK!".

innobackupex: Using mysql server version 5.6.22-72.0

innobackupex: Created backup directory /home/WorkSpace/xtrabackup

150424 16:40:59  innobackupex: Starting ibbackup with command: xtrabackup  --defaults-group="mysqld" --backup --suspend-at-end --target-dir=/tmp --tmpdir=/tmp --extra-lsndir='/tmp' --stream=tar
innobackupex: Waiting for ibbackup (pid=10463) to suspend
innobackupex: Suspend file '/tmp/xtrabackup_suspended_2'

xtrabackup version 2.2.3 based on MySQL server 5.6.17 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: )
xtrabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
xtrabackup: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
xtrabackup: cannot my_setwd /var/lib/mysql
innobackupex: Error: The xtrabackup child process has died at /usr/bin/innobackupex line 2672.
```

Can I run the backup on the other machine? If yes what else I need to install? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't run it on another machine, as it reads the data files directly, not via the mysql server process.

However, you can mount disk space of another machine on the database host and use this space as the target directory for the backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a different machine a mysql slave of the server you want to backup you can use xtrabackup on that machine.